# PGLM : negative binomial : In sqrt(diag(se)) : NaNs produced

Tags: count-data, poisson-regression

I have a question related to the count model.

1. I am trying to understand whether pickup and drop-offs influence road crash. Therefore, I have road crashes aggregated at the census tract level as my dependent variable (Y). Independent variables range from PUDO (Pickup & Dropoffs), Tot_VMT, which can be split into Tot Non-TNC VMT and Tot TNC VMT, Congested Speed (CSPD_1), and freeflow Speed (ff_SPEED).
2. I have two years of records: YR 2010 and YR 2016, so I am looking at a panel data model
3. Given that I am working on crash data, I am using Poisson/negative binomial distribution; hence using a package named PGLM
4. However, when I try to run the model (in any combination of X variables), most of the time, I get NaN with a warning message in sqrt(diag(se): NaNs produced

Question is:

1. What am I doing wrong, and is there a way to fix it?
2. Should I be using the panel data model, and is there another package you have
   used and are likely to recommend for such analysis?
3. I understand there are a few variations in the models for count data: Poisson/quasi-Poisson/NB/Zero-Inflated and Hurdle model. The question is how to use them in panel data

The dataset is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I060bXvUG8YOwmqf4LvmG9sXGRcOP4E_/view) and the script, I am using is as follows

```
res1_0 <- pglm(Total_Crash ~ Tot_VMT + PUDO,
           family="poisson",data=df,effect="twoways", model="within",
           index=c("tractce10_category","Accident_Year"))
```

summary(res1_0)
standard_se<-ginv(-res1_0$hessian)
coeftest(res1_0,standard_se)

Comment: As i understand it a panel consists of the same units being observed repeatedly. Is that the case here?

Comment: @mdewey, Yes. "tractce10_category" represents the entity and I measure the crashes for each given year.